# How to combine two SCSS selectors?

Tags: css, sass

I want to give a different color to the element if either of the two conditions exists.
Here is the code:

```
  .btn-link{
    color: $color-black;
    margin: 0;

  &:hover{
    color: $color-light-blue;
  }
  &:not(.collapsed){
    color: $color-light-blue;
  }
}
```

Everything is good, but it will be better if you can combine the two selectors

I already tried:

```
 &:hover&:not(.collapsed){
        color: $color-light-blue;
      }
```

But only the `hover` is identified

Comment: The way you wrote it meant both `:hover` and `:not(:collapsed)` simultaneously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same way as you do in CSS:

```
&:hover, &:not(.collapsed) {
    color: $color-light-blue;
}
```

This sets the color only if the element is in a hover state *or* doesn't have the class `collapsed`.

Answer (score 4):

You can put a comma between the two combining selectors, like this: `&:hover, &:not(.collapsed) {`

Full example:

HTML:

```html
<span class="btn-link">one class</span>
<span class="btn-link collapsed">two class</span>
```

CSS:

```css
$color-black: black;
$color-light-blue: lightblue;

.btn-link {
  color: $color-black;
  margin: 0;
  &:hover, &:not(.collapsed) {
    color: $color-light-blue;
  }
}
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/dwnfkLat/).

Sorry, no StackSnippet. We still can't handle SCSS here!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simple change your code

```css
/*SCSS*/
$color-light-blue : red;
.btn-link {
  &:hover:not(.collapsed) {
    color: $color-light-blue;
  }
}
/*compiled  CSS*/

.btn-link:hover:not(.collapsed) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<span class="btn-link">one class</span>
<span class="btn-link collapsed">two class</span>
```